# cheap rations or rations cheap

Tags: usage

Which one of the two sentences is correct

> He went to the wholesale market and bought the cheap rations.

> He went to the wholesale market and bought the rations cheap.

I think first one is correct, but in my book second one is correct. No further context is provided.

Comment: They are both correct. They are almost indistinguishable in meaning.

Comment: @green_ideas Why is the second one correct?

Comment: Adjective(cheap) is placed before Noun(rations)

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct but have slightly different meanings.

Bought the cheap rations means he bought those rations that were offered at a low price (relative to some other higher priced rations).

Bought the rations cheap suggests he bought the rations at a price he knew to be low relative to their real value.

Answer (score 1):

*He bought the cheap food* means that he chose the less expensive types of food.

*He bought the food cheap* (or cheaply) means that he got what he wanted for a low price.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have tried to explain the meaning, but not the grammar.

In *he bought the cheap rations*, *the cheap rations* is a noun phrase, with the adjective preceding the noun, as usual.

In *he bought the rations cheap*, the object noun phrase is *the rations*. *Cheap* is not part of this noun phrase, but a complement of the verb *bought*.

Consider another pair of sentences:

> He painted the red door

> He painted the door red.

The first is identifying the door as a red one - it is not clear whether it is the door that is red because he painted it, or it was red before he painted it. In the second, the door is not specified beyond "the door", but red was the colour he painted it.

In the same way *he bought the cheap rations* means that of all the rations available at the market, he bought the ones that were cheap (an unlikely thing to say, but possible). *He bought the rations cheap* means that he bought the (otherwise unidentified) rations for a low price.